# How to permanently remove menu icons from a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, menu

I have few fragments where i don't want to populate the menu so what i'am doing is i'm clearning the menu in every fragments as

```
menu.clear()
```

in the `oncreate()` method i have this

```
 setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

also i have navigation drawer on the right side whom i have locked on the right as

```
notificationDrawerFragment.mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(View.FOCUS_BACKWARD);
```

It worked but if i swipe from the right to left more than 3 times it pops up. How do i stop it??

Comment: what pops up? the menu comes back to the way it was?

Comment: where are you calling `clear()`, in what lifecycle method?

Comment: @Elltz yes, the menu pops up as it was

Comment: @Blundell i'm calling `menu.clear()` within `onCreateOption()` method

Comment: @silverFoxA probably better to do it in `onPrepareOptoonsMenu` but then you say that doesn't work below

Comment: yeah that's not working at all i tried